# What is the difference between min-content and max-content in a CSS Grid row?

Tags: css, css-grid

While I can see a difference between `min-content` and `max-content` values for the **column** size, when the text breaks with `min-content` and stretches as much as possible with `max-content` values, I don't see that effect in a row. Either the row size is defined with `min-content` or `max-content`, it seems not to take any effect. Is there any other practical use of `min-content` and `max-content` for the **rows** in a grid layout?

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content max-content;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px grey;
}

li:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #b9e2ff;
}

li:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #ffa733;
}

li:nth-child(3){
  background-color: #8b33ff;
}

li:nth-child(4){
  background-color: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello world hello world hello world hello world</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello world hello world hello world hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't really see a difference since in most of the case, the width is first defined based on the text then the height will get computed later.

You may see a difference if you have a vertical text where the logic is inverted:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content max-content;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px grey;
}
li {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
li:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #b9e2ff;
}

li:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #ffa733;
}

li:nth-child(3){
  background-color: #8b33ff;
}

li:nth-child(4){
  background-color: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello world hello world hello world hello world</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello world hello world hello world hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh, first I set `writing-mode` to the grid container rather than to the grid items and it was weird as columns became rows and vice versa.. and I gave up to test that property in any other ways.. Thanks, that seems to be one reasonable use